# Can thread_local be used to provide a static global variable in a dll for each thread?

Tags: c++, c++11, dll

I want to use the C++11 keyword [thread_local](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) in our Open Source library, which can be dynamically or statically linked on numerous platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac OS, ...), in the context of a static variable. This variable is of a class-type that basically just encapsulates a std::stringstream variable and initialises it to fit our stringstream formatting requirements. We want to have this statically available for performance reasons( see my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977457/efficiently-reading-two-comma-seperated-floats-in-brackets-from-a-string-without) for more details) and it is okay if this is done per thread.

The global variable should be used in a static templated class methods, which have to be implemented in a header. But this means, if I understand correctly, that a user of the library may include this header in their executable's code, which would compile the templated methods into the executable. These methods would then access the mentioned global variable from within the executable's thread. How do i need to declare/define the static variable for this to work, i.e. do I need to export the variable or the class type or is it enough to declare it "static thread_local X"? This is my current declaration:

```
// SharedStringstream.h
#include <sstream>
// Export stands for _declspec(dllimport) or (dllexport) respectively
class EXPORT SharedStringstream
{
public:
    SharedStringstream();

    static thread_local SharedStringstream s_sharedStreamInstance;

    std::stringstream d_sharedStream;
};
```

and the definition:

```
// SharedStringstream.cpp
#include "SharedStringStream.h"

SharedStringstream SharedStringstream::s_sharedStreamInstance();

SharedStringstream::SharedStringstream()
{
    d_sharedStream.imbue(std::locale("C"));
    d_sharedStream << std::skipws;
    d_sharedStream >> std::skipws;
}
```

Without export i get linker errors, with it I get the following error in Visual Studio 2015:

> Error C2492   'public: static SharedStringstream SharedStringstream::s_sharedStreamInstance': data with thread storage duration may not have dll interface

More info is given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40a45kxx.aspx) which basically states that a `thread_local` variable may not be exported. I would have to move it out of the class into my namespace for this purpose, is this the only way?

Furthermore:
The MSDN page on ["Thread Local Storage"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w1sdazb.aspx) says the following in regard to `thread_local` and DLLs:

> The use of the thread attribute may interfere with delay loading of DLL imports.

We do internally use delay-loading of DLLs for some plugins that our library consists of, but there will not be any calls to the variable. I assume users could, however, delay-load the library, although we do not officially support this. Assuming we do not support delay-loading of our library and do not call the variable from any delay-loaded dlls internally, are we able to be sure this will not be an issue in any context?

Are there any issues I have not considered in my question?

Comment: When you say 'for a static variable', do you really mean *as* a static variable? If not, what?

Comment: @EJP I rephrased it, better? I have no idea how to say it better. Please make a suggestion if it is still not understandable.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem, yet? I'm asking because I have the same issue...

Comment: @mattmilten no I haven't, our library code still looks pretty much like what I posted here. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Feels a bit like this xkcd comic: Wisdom of the Ancients https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: @mattmilten yes, only that I always reply :D For what it's worth, I did not encounter any issues with the setup we have atm yet, and no one complained.

Comment: Have you tried Boost, or did you find another solution? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the `thread_local` variable and not export it, and have static getter.

As the linked articled suggests, major limitations comes from the fact of not getting `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` message for already running threads.

To avoid both limitations:

- Have getter, and actual `thread_local` variable hidden in implementation non exported
- Lazy construct using constant-initialized null pointer, and construction on first request

Like this:

```cpp
// SharedStringstream.h
#include <sstream>
// Export stands for _declspec(dllimport) or (dllexport) respectively
class EXPORT SharedStringstream
{
public:
    SharedStringstream();

    static SharedStringstream& GetSharedStreamInstance();

    std::stringstream d_sharedStream;
}
```

```
// SharedStringstream.cpp
#include "SharedStringStream.h"

static thread_local std::unique_ptr<SharedStringstream> s_sharedStreamInstance;


/* static */ SharedStringstream& SharedStringstream::s_sharedStreamInstance() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<SharedStringstream>& inst = s_sharedStreamInstance;
    if (inst == nullptr)
    {
        inst = std::make_unique<SharedStringstream>();
    }
    return *inst;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When dll loads, it loads with it's own memory model. Hence, any static code will not shared across different processes.

Comment: I am not sure how this answers my question. I rephrased the topic a bit to make it clearer what I mean. In any case, would you mind to elaborate a bit more on your answer?