# QThreadStorage vs C++11 thread_local

Tags: qt, c++11, thread-local-storage

As the title suggests: What are the differences. I know that `QThreadStorage` existed long before the `thread_local` keyword, which is probably why it exists in the first place - but the question remains: Is there any significant difference in what they do between those two (except for the extended API of `QThreadStorage`).

Im am assuming a normal use case of a static variable - as using `QThreadStorage` as non static is possible, but not recommended to do.

```
static thread_local int a;
// vs
static QThreadStorage<int> b;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since Qt is open-source you can basically figure out the answers from the Qt sources. I am currently looking at 5.9 and here are some things, that I'd classify as significant:

1) Looking at `qthreadstorage.cpp`, the get/set methods both have this block in the beginning:

```
QThreadData *data = QThreadData::current();
if (!data) {
    qWarning("QThreadStorage::set: QThreadStorage can only be used with threads started with QThread");
    return 0;
}
```

So (an maybe this has changed/will change) you can't mix `QThreadStorage` with anything else than `QThread`, while the `thread_local` keyword does not have similar restrictions.

2) Quoting [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) on `thread_local`:

> **thread** storage duration. The object is allocated when the thread begins and deallocated when the thread ends.

Looking at `qthreadstorage.cpp`, the `QThreadStorage` class actually does not contain any storage for `T`, the actual storage is allocated upon the first get call:

```
QVector<void *> &tls = data->tls;
if (tls.size() <= id)
    tls.resize(id + 1);
void **v = &tls[id];
```

So this means that the lifetime is quite different between these two - with `QThreadStorage` you actually have more control, since you create the object and set it with the setter, or default initialize with the getter. E.g. if the ctor for the type could throw, with `QThreadStorage` you could catch that, with `thread_local` I am not even sure.

I assume these two are significant enough not to go any deeper.

Comment: `thread_local` is in effect `static` duration but in the context of a thread.

Comment: @Mgetz - yeah, I guess that is a more simple way to put the the second point.

Comment: Apparently, there is one more difference: on windows, `thread_local` cannot be an exported symbol - QThreadStorage however can be (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034857/can-thread-local-be-used-to-provide-a-static-global-variable-in-a-dll-for-each-t)