# Are scanf, printf and boost::lexical_cast fundamentally unsafe?

Tags: c++, printf, locale, scanf, lexical-cast

I recently had a bug converting a decimal string, e.g. `"10.057"`, to a `double`. The issue was with the global application locale, the use of `boost::lexical_cast` and the fact that some European locales use a `,` for the decimal point.

`scanf`, `printf` and other functions within this family have the same issue.

I am interested to hear how others deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of `scanf`, `printf`, `boost::lexical_cast` and related functions are dependent on the global application locale. They are therefore non-deterministic with respect to their input parameters. I have seen code like:

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
scanf(...);
```

However, this is not guaranteed to work in a multi-threaded environment.

A solution is to use functions and types that allow the user to explicitly specify the locale.

`iostream` stream objects allow the user to specify the locale as a parameter, and this will yield deterministic results.

```
std::istringstream istr("10.057");
istr.imbue(std::locale::classic());

double val;
istr >> val;
```

Similarly, `boost::format` allows the user to specify a locale as a parameter.

```
using boost::format;
std::string s = str(format("%lf", std::locale::classic()) % 10.057);
```

See also the discussion from a previous [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980423/locale-invariant-guarantee-of-boostlexical-cast).